# Importing Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

After updating all packages and try to re-install the maven plugin, I have the same problem.

I can't import the project !!

The error message is :

```
    "Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to 
read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-
plugin:jar:2.5 Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one 
of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5"
```

Comment: Could you please share all the pom.xml files?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your local repository(.m2 folder) and remove local cache. then try to import your project again.